# Some time On click listener is not working properly in android . hanging the phone and application is going irresponsive

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

[image]

Some times it will work properly some time going irresponsive as like shown in image please help me. Thanks

i am using bottom navigator and i have multiple fragments fragments contains rest API call and based on result  i'm creating some layouts, buttons and providing on click listener for them

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_home:
                SearchFragment dashBoardFragment = new SearchFragment(false, getApplicationContext());
                transaction.replace(R.id.linear_content, dashBoardFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_location:
                LocationFragment locationFragment = new LocationFragment(getApplicationContext());
                transaction.replace(R.id.linear_content, locationFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_search:
                SearchFragment dashBoardFragment1 = new SearchFragment(true, getApplicationContext());
                transaction.replace(R.id.linear_content, dashBoardFragment1);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.linear_content, profileFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Some buttons have on click listener like this

```
  phoneClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        final String location = obj.getLoc();
        chk_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + location));
                intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you include the stack-trace of the crash if any, or the code executed by the onClickListener?

Comment: @Yusuphwickama it is not throwing any exception simply going irresponsive

Comment: okay, can you show the code?